# how to adjust container's height based on listview itemCount?

Tags: flutter

I do have a problem adjust my container's height, I want my container's height to be dependent to it's content. However the container is almost taking up the entire screen(exclude appbar and bottom nav)

This is the sample snippet I've done.

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(10),
              ),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Color(0xffDDDDDD),
                  blurRadius: 6.0,
                  spreadRadius: 2.0,
                  offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                )
              ],
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 5,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return ListTile(
                              leading: const Icon(Icons.list),
                              trailing: const Text(
                                "GFG",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 15),
                              ),
                              title: Text("List item $index"));
                        }),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
```

I want my container's bottom in the black line that I've drawn and it should be dynamic if the items are less than 5. How do I do it using container?

TRIED: I tried searching some of it says that I should not putting a `height` and `width` and it automatically scale to its content. I would appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `Expanded` widget and set mainAxisSize.min for `Column`, set shrinkWrap to true in `ListView.builder`

```
child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                 ...
```